# detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0 while using selenium on mac

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Not sure why we are getting this error on mac 10.12.4 while running the selenium, My chrome is running on latest version i.e. Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) and Chrome driver is 2.9 and Selenium_java version is 2.53.

Anyone facing the same issue, is something i'm missing here or selenium is currently not supporting these configurations on mac Sierra. Any help much appreciated.

[image]

After this warning I'm getting this message, I'm running scripts using docker

```
[testng] Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
   [testng] Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bce', time: '2014-09-10 16:27:58'
   [testng] System info: host: 'vbabu-in-la01', ip: '10.40.17.78', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.4', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
   [testng] Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

Comment: Is this affecting any tests? It looks like it's just a warning.

Comment: Can you [try running this command](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/475) before running the tests? `export EVENT_NOKQUEUE=1`